# Cassandra - how to update a record with a compound key

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cql

In the process of learning Cassandra and using it on a small pilot project at work. I've got one table that is filtered by 3 fields:

```
CREATE TABLE webhook (
    event_id text,
    entity_type text,
    entity_operation text,
    callback_url text,
    create_timestamp timestamp,
    webhook_id text,
    last_mod_timestamp timestamp,
    app_key text,
    status_flag int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((event_id, entity_type, entity_operation))
);
```

Then I can pull records like so, which is exactly the query I need for this:

```
select * from webhook
where event_id = '11E7DEB1B162E780AD3894B2C0AB197A'
and entity_type = 'user'
and entity_operation = 'insert';
```

However, I have an update query to set the record inactive (soft delete), which would be most convenient by partition key in the *same* table. Of course, this isn't possible:

```
update webhook
set status_flag = 0
where webhook_id = '11e8765068f50730ac964b31be21d64e'
```

An example of why I'd want to do this, is a simple DELETE from an API endpoint:

```
http://myapi.com/webhooks/11e8765068f50730ac964b31be21d64e
```

Naturally, if I update based on the composite key, I'd potentially inactivate more records than I intend to.

Seems like my only choice, doing it the "Cassandra Way", is to use two tables; the one I already have and one to track status_flag by webhook_id, so I can update based on that id. I'd then have to select by webhook_id in the first table and disable it there as well? Otherwise, I'd have to force users to pass all the compound key values in the URL of the API's DELETE request.

Simple things you take for granted in relational data, seem to get complex very quickly in Cassandraland. Is this the case or am I making it more complicated than it really is?

Answer (score 0):

You can add webhook to your primary key.
So your table defination becomes somethign like this.

```
CREATE TABLE webhook (
event_id text,
entity_type text,
entity_operation text,
callback_url text,
create_timestamp timestamp,
webhook_id text,
last_mod_timestamp timestamp,
app_key text,
status_flag int,
PRIMARY KEY ((event_id, entity_type, entity_operation),webhook_id)
```

Now lets say you insert 2 records.

```
INSERT INTO dev_cybs_rtd_search.webhook(event_id,entity_type,entity_operation,status_flag,webhook_id) VALUES('11E7DEB1B162E780AD3894B2C0AB197A','user','insert',1,'web_id');

INSERT INTO dev_cybs_rtd_search.webhook(event_id,entity_type,entity_operation,status_flag,webhook_id) VALUES('12313131312313','user','insert',1,'web_id_1');
```

And you can update like following

```
update webhook
set status_flag = 0
where webhook_id = 'web_id' AND event_id = '11E7DEB1B162E780AD3894B2C0AB197A' AND entity_type = 'user'
AND entity_operation = 'insert';
```

It will only update 1 record.

However you have to send all the things defined in your primary key.

Comment: Right. "However you have to send all the things defined in your primary key." This is what I was asking, really. I can't do the soft-delete operation I want without first looking up the record, so I can pass in all the data to satisfy the entire key.

Comment: Then your only option is to do using cassandra way. There are secondary indexes also.You can take a look, but generally not recommended.